# How to add nodes and leaf value in a graph using java

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

This is the class below to create a graph in java which I got from leetcode. How can I generate a graph(check image) using this class as after generating the graph I will debug it as I am learning Graphs, BFS?

```
 class Node {
    public int val;
    public List<Node> children;

    public Node() {}

    public Node(int _val) {
        val = _val;
    }

    public Node(int _val, List<Node> _children) {
        val = _val;
        children = _children;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to at least attempt the code.  Start with a class called `Graph` that implements the graph behavior.

Comment: You can start by declaring Graph as a: `List<Node>`. Then, for each edge `a b`, you can insert `b` in `a's children list` and vice versa (if the graph is undirected).